# EXE JAR not functioning as expected

Tags: java, netbeans-7, executable-jar

I have created an `.exe` jar file of my project using `JartoExe` application(NetBeans 7.1.2 JDK7 ).Now for some classes it works just fine.But it does not shows up the GUI for/and after the specific class .

I have included all the dependencies needed.But the GUI won't show up after a perticular class.What is wrong with `.exe` file?Have I missed something?

**UPDATE**
On the Console, it's throwing `FileNotFound` Exception.My files are in the current project folder.So, what should i need to change?

Is this because of  `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` ?

Exception details:

```
Mar 07, 2013 10:57:07 PM projectfinal.KaraokeTest$3 run
SEVERE: null
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Na Kajre Ki Dhar.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at projectfinal.KaraokeTest.initComponents(KaraokeTest.java:89)
    at projectfinal.KaraokeTest.<init>(KaraokeTest.java:35)
    at projectfinal.KaraokeTest$3.run(KaraokeTest.java:375)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: *"using EXEtoJAR"* Are you sure that is not 'Jar to Exe'?

Comment: @AndrewThompson so silly of me.Will just edit.

Comment: When you launch the Exe from the command line, do you see any output for the failing apps.?  Why not launch them using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)?

Comment: have you set main class? did you try to run it on a machine with no java installed? if not, any error in the console/cmd?

Comment: I don't launch it from command line.Just double click the exe Jar.I don't see any output for the failing app.

Comment: you have to launch it from command line to see if there is any error. otherwise, there won't be any place to see the error.

Comment: @gigadot will try to run from cmd.Let you know the results.

Comment: @gigadot does not gives me an error or something from CMD.

Comment: Does the code contain `catch` statements that ignore the error?  Also, why am I still waiting on an answer to 'why not JWS'?  I don't ask these questions for my own amusement.

Comment: @AndrewThompson can JWS create an exe file?

Comment: @gigadot  It does not need to.  It can do better by deploying Jars and natives to Windows, **Linux & OS X**.  Why on Earth would you want to limit a Java app. to just Windows?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I think it's more like an error. :/

Comment: @AndrewThompson using it in JWS, gives me the same result..

Comment: What is in the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) when launched using JWS?  Without further (specific) information about the cause of the problem, none of us has a snowball's chance in Hell of solving it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oh thanks for the idea of Console...my problem is half solved...!!!It's throwing file not found exception.But on netbeans, everything is fine...will make an update

Comment: *"Is the cause of getClass().getResourceAsStream() ?"*  That does not make sense to me as a sentence.  Are you asking if you should use `getResourceAsStream()` instead of `File`?  I would tend to use `getResource()` for an URL instead, but one of those two methods should be used for any [tag:embedded-resource] that the app. uses.  As far as the error output goes, best to copy/paste it as an edit to the question (and use code formatting).

Comment: OK - I was hoping it might 'give away' some things I did not already know, but it turns out not.  Can you confirm whether `Na Kajre Ki Dhar.txt` is effectively a part of the app. (an application resource)?  If not:  What is in it & what is it for? Where does it come from (you, the user)..?

Comment: @AndrewThompson "Na Kajre Ki Dhar.txt" is under my project's folder.This may look odd, but when i Run my project through NetBeans (jws) No problem.But same thing gives this Exception when tried from command prompt! and same error through .exe file.

Comment: @AndrewThompson ahh in process of finding out the bug, I used both jws and .exe.I found out that (jws) is much more faster (executes things) than .exe.Is it?Or I am just imagining things?

Comment: (shrugs) I never turn Java apps. into EXEs so have nothing to compare it by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very often jars don't have directories.so `getClass().getResourceAsStream(somefile)` should be `getClass().getResourceAsStream("\somefile")`.